# Upgraded winforms app now getting NullReferenceException calling menuitems PerformClick method, any ideas?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

**Background:**

A WinForms app, originally written in .NET 1.1 migrated via Visual
Studio to .NET 4.0. Typical menu bar at the top of main app form (NB:
not migrated to ToolStripMenuItem), as you might expect there is a
File menuitem that contains an Exit menu item.

I have implemented Ctrl-L shortcut which will bring up a modal lock
form. I also have a timer component on the main form which will
automatically bring up the lock form if there's no activity for
configurable amount of time.

When the lock form is shown you can either unlock (requiring user to
login again) or quit. If you choose to quit then my code does a
fileExitMenuItem.PerformClick() call.

**Problem:**

For some strange reason after the migration if I quit from the lock
form which was displayed either automatically or due to Ctrl-L
shortcut then I get a NullReferenceException thrown on the
fileExitMenuItem.PerformClick() line of code.

fileExitMenuItem is not null; with break-when-exception-thrown
switched on I can browse all of fileExitMenuItems properties.

I can break in the designer code of the form and watch the click event
handler being attached. If I use the File >> Exit menu item directly I
can break on the code in the event handler.

So this is a total WTF moment. Any suggestions on what to look at will be greatly appreciated

[UPDATE 1] As requested here is some code - this method is called whenever the user presses Ctrl-L or the lock timer elapses:

```
private void LockApplication()
    {
        try 
        {
            // Stop the timer so we don't get any more elapsed events whilst we are waiting
            // for a user to respond to the lockdown dialog. In addition stop the callout reminder
            // time as once we have locked we don't want that doing it's thing.
            lockdownTimer.Stop();
            calloutsReminderTimer.Stop();

            // Clone the current identity so we can check it later.
            var previousIdentity = (CudosIdentity)BOUtilities.CurrentIdentity.Clone();

            // Show lockdown form.
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result;
            using (var lockForm = new Forms.applicationLockedForm())
                result = lockForm.ShowDialog(this);

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Did we unlock with a different login?
                if (!previousIdentity.Equals(BOUtilities.CurrentIdentity))
                {
                    // Yes, so lose all changes.
                    CloseOpenForms();
                    if (_currentLoadSpec != null)
                        _currentLoadSpec.CancelContent();
                }

                RefreshLockTimerSetting(null);
            }
            else
                fileExitMenuItem.PerformClick();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helper.LogError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            lockdownTimer.Start();
            calloutsReminderTimer.Start();
        }
    }
```

This is the code for the exit menu item:

```
private void fileExitMenuItem_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

When the following line in LockApplication method from above is called I get the NullReferenceException:

```
fileExitMenuItem.PerformClick();
```

[UPDATE 2] Call stack info when the above line is executed:

```
    [External Code]
```

> Cudos.exe!Cudos.mainForm.LockApplication() Line 1132 + 0x10 bytes   C#
>       Cudos.exe!Cudos.mainForm.fileLockCudosMenuItem_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 1594 + 0x8 bytes   C#
>       [External Code] 
>       Cudos.exe!Cudos.mainForm.Main() Line 1880 + 0x1d bytes  C#
>       [External Code]

Comment: Do you have any event that executes when you try to close your application? For example a Form_Closing event on the Login form. By the way, which code is executed in the menu event?

Comment: I have a form closing event handler which checks for unsaved changed and cancels the event if the user answers with the Cancel button of a yes/no/cancel prompt. If the event does not get cancelled my timer component is stopped.

Comment: Oh and the code in the exit menu items event handler is a call to Application.Exit()

Comment: Put a breakpoint there then and follow what happen there. Just to be sure that the exception is not raised there

Comment: Breakpoint in formclosing handler doesn't get hit, nor does a breakpoint in the exit menuitems handler when quiting from the lock form menu.

Comment: What about your Click event handler for your `fileExitMenuItem`? Maybe the exception was thrown in that event handler, sometimes the code line which raises exception is not highlighted as you expected. I've encountered such a case many times.

Comment: @KingKing - see comment from 2 secs before yours, :P

Comment: @KingKing - I've got break-when-exception-thrown switched on too and it's breaking on that fileExitMenuItem.PerformClick() line.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense much to me. What is the code in the Click event handler? Have you tried commenting out all the code in there?

Comment: This question looks like it is quoting somebody else's problem.  Do document your problem better.  Post relevant code snippets and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @KingKing As in above comments, the code in the click event handler doesn't even get hit, but just on the off chance commented it out and still same result.

Comment: @HansPassant I used the blockquote option just to get a bit of indendation under the "Background" and "Problem" headings

Comment: if so, I'm sure to say that your `fileExitMenuItem` is null. I think you can call the `Quit` method directly yourself without calling `PerformClick()`

Comment: Well as in the question details fileExitMenuItem is not null I can QuickWatch all its details.

Comment: The Stack Trace of the exception is fundamental here.

Comment: Just added trace see above

Comment: What if you replace `fileExitMenuItem.PerformClick();` with `Application.Exit();`? Any exception?

Comment: That stack trace isn't very useful, do run the Debug build of your program.  And enable unmanaged debugging and the Microsoft Symbol server, high odds that some kind on unmanaged code is causing this exception.

Comment: It is possible that the Windows timer reenters its execution code? You call PerformClick then Application.Exit, but the finally clause restart the timers. What happen in the tick event?

Comment: that code is wrapped by a try-catch but still throws exception, I've encountered such a case and most of them are strange.

Comment: @HansPassant - I am running in debug build (always do whilst developing). I've gone into Tools >> Options >> Debugging - Symbols and ticked the Microsoft Symbol Servers loading symbols for all modules. Not sure about enabling unmanaged code, how would I do that?

Comment: @KingKing - I've got the break-when-exception-thrown option switched on, if I continue stepping through the code it goes into the catch and finally blocks as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave up and just hacked it by changing the fileExitMenuItem.PerformClick() to Application.Exit(). So I still don't have any idea why it was throwing the exception but it at least now works. I guess if I put more logic into the fileExitMenuItem click handler I will just have to remember to extract it into a method and update this hack to call that method to.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I will try to remove the restart of the timers if you call the Perform_Click.
The Tick event could be called when there is no more the application because you call Application.Exit().

```
private void LockApplication()
{
    try 
    {
        lockdownTimer.Stop();
        calloutsReminderTimer.Stop();

        .....

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ......
            lockdownTimer.Start();
            calloutsReminderTimer.Start();
        }
        else
            fileExitMenuItem.PerformClick();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Helper.LogError(ex);
        lockdownTimer.Start();
        calloutsReminderTimer.Start();
    }
    // remove the finally clause

}
```

Comment: The finally block doesn't get run until after the exception occurs on the fileExitMenuItem.PerformClick() line. I have removed the finally block (although made no difference) because the application will be closed after the error is logged any way and if this exception wasn't being thrown it would be exiting any way.

Comment: Changing `Application.Exit` in `Environment.Exit(1)` ?

Comment: And even using `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` would surely end everything :)  - I had to do so instead of `Application.Exit()` in a project of mine.